# Sorting Data in Excel Based On Groups

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table shown below. I want to sort the columns alphabetically in respect to their respective groups in regards to the store number.
So for example in store 960 i would like the type to start from blue barrels etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Please note: this is sample data and the real data is in the exact same format but 9000 rows

[image]

Comment: Try SORTBY() function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Select all the data (do not select the 2 rows on the top). Press "Sort" on the "Data" ribbon. Check "My data has headers" if it is unchecked. In the dropdown menu next to Sort By choose "Store Num". Then press on "Add level". In the dropdown menu next to Then By choose "Type". Pay attention to their orders. Then press OK.